Can an Avalanche fit a Chevy 1993 transmission
AvalancHe 2005 transmission from a Chevy 1993 fits yes or no

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

In a word: No
The problem is, while the body of the 4L60E is the same between them, how they are controlled and operate is completely different.
